# Call ffmeg from a batch script plugin

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file

I am working on a batch plugin which should quickly reduce images. The idea is that you simply drag and drop your image on the `.bat`, and it reduces your image. I am calling `ffmpeg` for that, but I have a problem with `ffmpeg`'s path. Indeed I don't want `ffmpeg` to be called on my computer, but locally, in the plugin's folders.

Here's what I tried:

```
set ffmpegpath=..\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe

set inputPath=%1

set inputFolder=%1\..

set image_name=%~n1

set resolution=512

if exist "%1.png" goto:png
if exist "%1.jpg" goto:jpg
if exist "%1.jpeg" goto:jpeg

:png
set image_extension=png
goto:done

:jpg
set image_extension=jpg
goto:done

:jpeg
set image_extension=jpeg
goto:done

:done
echo image_extension is %image_extension%



%ffmpegpath% -i %1 -vf scale=%resolution%:%resolution% %image_name%_reduced.%image_extension%


pause
```

I have searched the internet and tried many combinations, but I still get an error saying that the system didn't find the path. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reference the file path of the batch file, you can use the `%~dp0` variable.

These are described in what may not be an obvious place; the documentation for the `for` loop (`for /?`).

In this documentation `I` can be replaced with the argument number. Argument `0` always holds the path to the batch file, including the filename.

```
%~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
%~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
%~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
%~pI        - expands %I to a path only
%~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
%~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
%~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
%~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
%~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
%~zI        - expands %I to size of file
%~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
               environment variable and expands %I to the
               fully qualified name of the first one found.
               If the environment variable name is not
               defined or the file is not found by the
               search, then this modifier expands to the
               empty string
```

Therefore, in your case you should be able to use:

```
set ffmpegpath=%~dp0..\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe
```

It is also good practice to surround this with quotes when calling it, in case the path has spaces:

```
"%ffmpegpath%" -i %1 -vf scale=%resolution%:%resolution% %image_name%_reduced.%image_extension%
```

Comment: YES ! That was it. Thank you ! I had seen the %~dp0 variable, but until now I had always managed without it. Good to know ! Thanks again !